# Laravel Spatie Roles get current users role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using laravels Spatie/Roles is there a way to get the current users role who is logged in?

I've tried

```
if($this->hasRole('admin')) { //do something }
```

but it wont work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out, for those of you out there this is how you do it.

```
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('my_role_name'))
{
    // do something
}
  //otherwise do something else
```

Comment: what if user has no role ?

Answer (score 26):

In your Model that uses the [`Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Traits/HasRoles.php) trait, which is in most cases `User`, you can call various methods for verifying or retrieving roles.
They are:

- `roles`
- `hasRole`
- `hasAnyRole`
- `hasAllRoles`
- `getRoleNames`

### Usage example

For a given user,

```
$roles = $user->getRoleNames();// Returns a collection
```

[Reference here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage).

Answer (score 16):

```php
{{ Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name') }}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 12):

If you know that the user has only one role (for example: "customer") then you can have this displayed as follows:

```php
{{ Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')[0] ?? '' }}
// or with the auth() helper:
{{ auth()->user()->roles->pluck('name')[0] ?? '' }}

// output: "customer"
```

Then you can check in your blade File:

```php
@if ( auth()->user()->roles->pluck('name')[0] ?? '' === 'customer' )
   <h1>Hello Customer {{auth()->user()->name }}</h1>
    ...
@endif
```

Or even much simpler:

```php
@role('customer')
    I am a Customer!
@else
    I am not a Customer ...
@endrole
```

Comment: Yes role is much simpler, but sadly vscode blade extension not yet recognize it. Hope it will, soon.

Answer (score 5):

I getting the current loged in Admin user name using

```
$user->getRoleNames()->first();
```

And getting the response is

> "Super Admin"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34153641)

Answer (score 4):

Using Laravel 9 and Spatie v5 you can use

Controller

```
if(auth()->user()->hasRole('name')){}
```

Blade

```
@role('name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using laravel8 and spattie  5.5

If users **only HAVE ONE ROLE**; you can use:

> auth()->user()->roles->pluck("id")->first()

to get the role id for the current logged user,
optionally can use:

> auth()->user()->roles->pluck("name")->first();

to get the role's name

Answer (score -1):

Auth::user()->getRoleNames();

This will return a collection with all the roles the user has attached to.